# Button click event not fired after upgrading to Sitecore 7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I have recently upgraded from Sitecore 6.5 to Sitecore 7.2.  I have worked through a number of issues, refactored search, etc.  However, on pages other than the homepage my `<asp:Button />` were not submitting the form due to `__doPostback` being undefined.  To resolve this I added an `<asp:ScriptManager />` to my layout and now the javascript fires on click and the form is submitted/reloaded.

The problem I'm having now is that my server-side click event handler is not being fired for any buttons on that page.

Below is my code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login Page.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="MyProject.layouts.Login.Login_Page" %>

<asp:Button ID="TestButton" runat="server" OnClick="TestButton_OnClick" />
```

And my codebehind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyProject.layouts.Login
{
    public partial class Login_Page : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {        
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void TestButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

On click the event is never fired.  Any ideas out there?  I'm thinking it might be related to the same reason the pages didn't have `__doPostback` defined.

Comment: Do you have caching enabled for your pages/sublayouts? That would usually cause the codebehind not to be hit on a second request

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate that now.

Comment: @jammykam That was exactly it.  I disabled cacheHtml on my site node and things are working.  I will track down the control with caching now and turn it off. If you make an answer to that effect, I can mark this as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have caching enabled for your sublayout/rendering, then this is the expected behaviour since the rendered HTML is cached and your server side code will not be triggered after first load. Meaning the Page_Load event will not be re-triggered neither  will your Click event for your button.

The easiest way to check is if it is a caching issue is to clear the cache (via /sitecore/admin/cache.aspx) and see if your event is triggered. You could also disable the cache in the  element by setting `cacheHtml="false"`. This will help you identify the caching issue, you should fix the underlying issue by disabling caching for that control.